# iron meteor cannot find simpl-schema

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, simpl-schema

I am using [iron-meteor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iron-meteor) for scaffolding meteor crud apps and I am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/meteor-js/how-to-build-web-apps-ultra-fast-with-meteor-iron-scaffolding-and-automatic-form-generation-11734eda8e67). I have iron meteor running but the problem arises when I install aldeed collections and other packages as follows;

```
iron add twbs:bootstrap aldeed:collection2 aldeed:autoform aldeed:delete-button momentjs:moment accounts-password ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
```

I also have;

`npm install -g --save simpl-schema`

But I get errors when I run 
`iron run`

W20190716-20:45:24.894(2)? (STDERR) WARNING: npm peer requirements (for aldeed:collection2) not installed:
W20190716-20:45:24.894(2)? (STDERR) - simpl-schema@>=0.0.0 not installed

I have tried changing npm directory rights and permissions to ensure that the current user has access to npm packages. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling `aldeed:collections2` package and `simpl-schema` but the same error still persists

> => Started proxy.
>   => Started MongoDB.                            W20190716-20:45:24.686(2)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a
>   pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt. W20190716-20:45:24.714(2)?
>   (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to
>   be W20190716-20:45:24.714(2)? (STDERR) approximately three times
>   slower than the native implementation. W20190716-20:45:24.719(2)?
>   (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
>   W20190716-20:45:24.720(2)? (STDERR)  W20190716-20:45:24.720(2)?
>   (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt W20190716-20:45:24.720(2)?
>   (STDERR)  W20190716-20:45:24.720(2)? (STDERR) in the root directory of
>   your application. W20190716-20:45:24.894(2)? (STDERR) WARNING: npm
>   peer requirements (for aldeed:collection2) not installed:
>   W20190716-20:45:24.894(2)? (STDERR)  - simpl-schema@>=0.0.0 not
>   installed. W20190716-20:45:24.894(2)? (STDERR) 
>   W20190716-20:45:24.895(2)? (STDERR) Read more about installing npm
>   peer dependencies: W20190716-20:45:24.895(2)? (STDERR)
>   http://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies
>   W20190716-20:45:24.895(2)? (STDERR)  W20190716-20:45:24.937(2)?
>   (STDERR)
>   /home/kingzuru/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.1ehy8qi.j0unh++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
>   W20190716-20:45:24.940(2)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
>   W20190716-20:45:24.941(2)? (STDERR)                       ^ W20190716-20:45:24.941(2)?
>   (STDERR)  W20190716-20:45:24.941(2)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find
>   module 'simpl-schema' W20190716-20:45:24.942(2)? (STDERR)     at
>   makeMissingError (packages/modules-runtime.js:222:12)
>   W20190716-20:45:24.942(2)? (STDERR)     at Module.require
>   (packages/modules-runtime.js:241:17) W20190716-20:45:24.942(2)?
>   (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:258:21)
>   W20190716-20:45:24.943(2)? (STDERR)     at collection2.js
>   (packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:13:22)
>   W20190716-20:45:24.943(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate
>   (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7) W20190716-20:45:24.943(2)?
>   (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
>   W20190716-20:45:24.944(2)? (STDERR)     at require
>   (packages/modules-runtime.js:258:21) W20190716-20:45:24.944(2)?
>   (STDERR)     at
>   /var/www/testapp/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/aldeed_collection2.js:895:15
>   W20190716-20:45:24.944(2)? (STDERR)     at
>   /var/www/testapp/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/aldeed_collection2.js:902:3
>   W20190716-20:45:24.945(2)? (STDERR)     at
>   /var/www/testapp/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:419:36
>   W20190716-20:45:24.945(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach ()
>   W20190716-20:45:24.945(2)? (STDERR)     at
>   /var/www/testapp/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:228:19
>   W20190716-20:45:24.945(2)? (STDERR)     at
>   /var/www/testapp/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:479:5
>   W20190716-20:45:24.945(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run
>   (/var/www/testapp/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
>   W20190716-20:45:24.946(2)? (STDERR)     at
>   /var/www/testapp/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:478:11
>   => Exited with code: 1

Comment: If it is just the Meteor project try 'meteor add aldeed:simple-schema' . More info is here:
https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/simple-schema

Comment: I'm not using meteor outright, I am using iron-meteor found here, https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-cli

Comment: Even then, it is meteor project at the end of the day.
Can you check if .meteor/version file has `aldeed:simple-schema@1.3.0`
From the link of your tutorial:
https://github.com/seeschweiler/medium-issuetracker/tree/master/app/.meteor

Secondly, I believe it should be 
`meteor npm install --save simpl-schema`    . Check the Atmosphere Readme of the `aldeed:collection2` -> https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/collection2

Answer (score 1):

The command `npm install -g --save simpl-schema` installs Simple Schema on a **global** level (`-g` option means [install globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html)) and thus it won't be usable on your local project.

You should rather do `meteor npm install --save simpl-schema` inside your project.

Note, that `aldeed:simple-schema` is deprecated, as well as `aldeed:collection2-core` (which is why you should use `aldeed:collection2`).

Comment: I have ran  meteor npm install --save simpl-schema but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Inside the project folder? Can you rebuild using `meteor reset`?

Comment: I did run     iron reset 
and ran the application but I am still hitting the same error.

Comment: Can you provide a repo with a minimal project due reproduce?

Comment: I don't have a repo but what I did was just to follow the above sited tutorial and installed all the mentioned packages that's when a hit simpl-schema errors.
 
For now, I noticed that iron scaffolding is working fine and as workaround I use it to generated files then I copy them over to a pure meteor application which has no problems with simple-schema or aldeed packages. It's a long process but it gets me through.